# Fix HTML5 floating issues

Tags: html, css, position

When I use aside, section, and footer together, and I use "float:left" on the section the footer acts like it's "position:absolute" and bypasses both aside and section and goes to the top of the page even though I don't have any positions designated in CSS. Additionally, the section takes up the entire page, overlapping aside.  It doesn't matter if I use HTML5, or revert everything back to divs and ids, the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?  Why is it doing that? and how do I fix it?

My CSS:

```
aside {
     padding: 2%;
     min-height: 863px;
     width: 10%;
     float: left;
}

section {
     padding: 2%;
     width: 80%;
     float:left;
 }

 footer {
     height: 80px;
     padding: 2%;
     background: lightblue;
 }
```

My HTML:

```
    <aside>
       <p>This is the aside</p>
    </aside>
    <section>
        This is the section
    </section>
    <footer>
      This is the footer
    </footer>
```

Comment: If you wan't to move down you `<footer>` you can try to define `clear: both;` on it. The question is why would you need `float` on those elements in the first place? I mean if you define them that they make up a 100% or less they will be laid out side by side anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float: ...` was intended for wrapping text around an image and overused for layout purposes. You could slap a `clear: both;` on the footer and call it a day (also your padding is adding width in addition to your percentage widths - add `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`).

For modern times, `display: flex;` is the way to go...

HTML

```
<body>
  <main-section>
    <aside>
      <p>This is the aside</p>
    </aside>
    <section>
      This is the section
    </section>
  </main-section>
  <footer>
    This is the footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

aside {
  min-height: 863px;
  flex: 1;
}

main-section {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 8;
}

footer {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 80px;
}
```